# How can I set a parent / child relationship using the Elastic Search Java API?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, parent-child

I'm trying to create two documents, one build a child of the other, using the Elastic Search Java API.

My code looks something like this:

```
public void createRecord(Road road, Car car) throws Exception{
  ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

  String roadJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(road);
  String carJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(car);

  Client client = TransportClient.builder().build().addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300));

  IndexResponse response = client.prepareIndex("myIndex", "roadType").setSource(roadJson).get();

  client.prepareIndex("myIndex", "carType").setParent(response.getId()).setSource(carJson).get();
}
```

This code successfully creates a road document but when it goes to create a car document I get the error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't specify parent if no parent
>   field has been configured

How can I properly create two Elastic documents that form a parent / child relationship with the ES Java API?

Comment: What do your mappings look like?  Do you specify a _parent type for road in your car mapping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are not configuring your "carType" mapping to specify "roadType" as a parent.

```
"mappings": {
    "roadType": {
        "properties": {
        }
    },
    "carType": {
        "_parent": {
            "type": "roadType"
        },
        "properties": {
            "make": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "model": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For more info, see here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/parent-child-mapping.html

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using the dynamic mappers...  Is there anyway to configure a parent - child relationship with them?

Comment: You could try dynamically adding a parent mapping to your carType before your index request, if it doesn't already exist, like so: ``client.admin().indices().preparePutMapping("myIndex").setType("carType").setSource(MAPPING INFO FOR PARENT DECLARATION)``  The JSON would look something along the lines of { "_parent": { "type": "roadType" } }

Edit: saw you already figured this part out.  The reason in the end was that your mapping was not configured.

Answer (score 0):

I had to create a custom mapper for the parent / child relationship.  This still preserves the dynamic mapping that can happen on document creation.

```
public void createRecord(Road road, Car car) throws Exception{
  ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

  String roadJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(road);
  String carJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(car);

  Client client = TransportClient.builder().build().addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300));

  if(!client.admin().indices().prepareExists("myIndex").get().isExists()){ 
     XContentBuilder xContentBuilder = XContentFactory.jsonBuilder().startObject().startObject("roadType").endObject().endObject();
     XContentBuilder xContentBuilder2 = XContentFactory.jsonBuilder().startObject().startObject("carType").startObject("_parent").field("type", "roadType").endObject().endObject().endObject();

     client.admin().indices().create(new CreateIndexRequest("myIndex")).get();
     client.admin().indices().preparePutMapping("myIndex").setType("carType").setSource(xContentBuilder2).get();
     client.admin().indices().preparePutMapping("myIndex").setType("roadType").setSource(xContentBuilder).get();
  }

  IndexResponse response = client.prepareIndex("myIndex", "roadType").setSource(roadJson).get();

  client.prepareIndex("myIndex", "carType").setParent(response.getId()).setSource(carJson).get();
}
```

This creates a custom mapper that sets up the parent child relationship between roadType and carType while still allowing you to dynamically map additional properties.  Make sure you add the child mapping first or it won't work.